# How to make a button that opens an html page?

Tags: html

Hello I'm trying to code a calculator for fun and I was wondering how to make an html button not a hyperlink and the button when you click it will bring you to another html page in that folder.

Thanks, lions

Comment: have you googled it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to put the button into a form like this:

```
<form action="stackoverflow.com">
     <input type="submit" value="Button Text">
</form>
```

Comment: No I want it to go into the local folder and I want it to be universal so that you don't have to specify the directory when you use it

Comment: Do you mean using relative paths? Here is a nice website about it: http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/